# Can you recover regression coefficients from quantile regression coefficients on censored data?

Tags: generalized-linear-model, model-comparison, censoring, quantile-regression

Suppose you have data that you know to be well-fit by a GLM with a specified link and variance function. You would like to estimate that model. However, you do  not have access to the data; instead, you have the results from a quantile regression on the same data using the same independent variables.

An alternative framing for my problem is that the data is right-censored. Quantile regression up the the censorship line is consistent; ordinary regression, linear or non-linear, is not. You  can sometimes eliminate the bias with a two-stage process that uses other variables to predict whether an observation will lie in the censored range. But in my  case the other variables predict this only very weakly, so this procedure increases the variance a lot.

Can you recover the GLM regression coefficients from quantile regression coefficients? Or even linear coefficients?

Comment: I don't think you can recover the actual data from your quantile regression coefficients but you could try to generate a dataset predicted by you quantile regression estimates and then analyze that dataset using GLM. Ofcourse this dataset itself would only be 'predicted' values.